# Difference between MobileFirst Platform 8.0 and MaaS360?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Can anyone tell me what is the **difference between MobilFirst Platform 8.0 and MaaS360**? Are both servers?

I have used MobileFirst Platform 8.0, where I have MobileFirst server 8.0 (installed(dev) from IBM website), Java Adapter & Mobile Application(hybrid and native). We used to deploy Adapter and Register mobile application in MobileFirst Server.

But now we are **exploring MaaS360** so I just wanted to know what exactly it is? Is a server like MobilFirst 8.0? can we integrate it with my MobileFirst server? where and how Adapter will come in the picture?

It will be very helpful if someone explain me the **complete flow diagram for this(including Mobile device , server, adapter, backend server or apis).**

Thanks in advance

Sharda

Answer (score 4):

The products are related, but really quite different.  MaaS360 is all about endpoint management.  For instance, at IBM we use MaaS360 to allow mobile enterprise applications to run on employee owned devices over a public network.

Mobile Foundation by contrast is a tool to facilitate multi-platform mobile application development and management.  Mobile Foundation includes very robust security features, secure access to back-end resources, Push Notifications, Analytics capabilities and ships an Application Center than can be used for distributing Enterprise Apps.

So they are really quite different in their intent and can be used in a complimentary fashion.

Make Sense?

Comment: Ok. Thanks John to clear confusion about these two products. Still I have some doubts. I have already developed an application(mobile app/ adapter) using MobileFirst sdk so I just wanted to know can I use both MaaS360 amd MobileFirst together (by some configurations/ mapping) or i will have to re write whole thing again.